# vim : what is this window and How can I invoke/close this

Tags: vim

[image]

Sometimes windows like this pop up. I can get out of with with `:q` but I wonder, how did i end up with this? Maybe there is some keystroke combinations involved but I have no idea. Can you link me with relevant information for this feature of vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the command-line window.

You invoke it with `q:` and you can read all about it in `:help cmdline-window`.

In short: you get access to your latest Ex commands and a chance to edit them and re-execute them with all of Vim's editing power.

Comment: Also: it can be closed like any other window, or by pressing enter on any element of the history (which executes it).

Comment: Pressing `<c-c>` will close the window and return you to the command line. See `:h E199` for more information on closing the cmdline-window. However if you are like me and want to use `<esc>` to close the window then add this to your `~/.vimrc` file: `autocmd CmdwinEnter * nnoremap <buffer> <esc> :q<cr>`

Answer (score 1):

it is command-line window. You could open it by pressing `q:` or `ctrl-f (in command line)`

to close it, you could `:q`

for more details, check `:h q:`

I think it is good feature. We can not only choose previous command from that window, but also edit command with vim way.

similarly vim has `q/` too. search history.

Answer (score 0):

As above answers refer, it is a feature called 'command-line window'.

Usually it is a typo of `:q`, you can disable it by

```
nnoremap q: :q
```

Answer (score 0):

See other answers for explanation of "what" the window is.

I'll address how to close the window since that part seems to have been overlooked:

use `<C-c>` (ctrl + 'C').